# Acknowledge Receipt Tag in Docusign Request

Tags: docusignapi

I want to send the document to a reviewer who doesn't need to be sign the document. Once he view the document then document should go to signers.
How to achieve this?

I got the info about recipient type from docusign site and got the details about "Acknowledge receipt" type.
http://www.docusign.com/support/docusign/faq

It is working as expected from docusign web site.

Now I am trying to achieve the same through code, but it is now working.
Either I am building incorrect request or this "Acknowledge receipt" is not supported through code!!!!!

Please see the below code snippet, I am trying to send acknowledge receipt to some recipients, but not getting succeeded. Also looked in your community & guide for REST API, but did not find anything related to this tag “acknowledge receipt”. Please help me out with suitable format for this tag & how to use it.

```
string envDef = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\'" + strEnvDefUrl + "'>" +
               "<emailBlurb>This comes from C#</emailBlurb>" +
               "<emailSubject>From Code Behind - API Call for adding signature request to document and sending</emailSubject>" +
               "<status>sent</status>" +
               // add document(s)                                      
               "<documents>" +
               "<document>" +
               "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
               "<name>" + strfileName + "</name>" +
               "</document>" +
               "</documents>" +
               // add recipient(s)                                     
               "<recipients>" +
               "<acknowledgeReceipt>" +
               "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" +
               "<routingOrder>1</routingOrder>" +
               "<email>abc@test.com</email>" +
               "<name>Rajesh</name>" +
               "</acknowledgeReceipt>" +
               "<signers>" +
               sbCustomer +
               "</signers>" +
               "</recipients>" +
               "</envelopeDefinition>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAQ that you've referenced applies to the Console, not the API.  In the API these types of recipients are still called **CertifiedDeliveries**.  Please read the API documentation as it explains this.  [This page in particular shows the certified deliveries type](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Recipients/Certified%20Deliveries%20Recipient.htm) although the example request body is in JSON format not XML.

To fix your XML body you need to change from acknowledgeReceipt to certifiedDeliveries, however, you also need one extra XML node.  You need the plural

```
<certifiedDeliveries>
```

node to tell the system you are about to provide a list of certified delivery recipients, but then you need a singular `<certifiedDelivery>` node for each recipient of this type.  Therefore, using the request body you've provided your XML formatted request should look like this:

```
string envDef = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\'" + strEnvDefUrl + "'>" +
           "<emailBlurb>This comes from C#</emailBlurb>" +
           "<emailSubject>From Code Behind - API Call for adding signature request to document and sending</emailSubject>" +
           "<status>sent</status>" +
           // add document(s)                                      
           "<documents>" +
           "<document>" +
           "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
           "<name>" + strfileName + "</name>" +
           "</document>" +
           "</documents>" +
           // add recipient(s)                                     
           "<recipients>" +
           "<certifiedDeliveries>" +
           "<certifiedDelivery>" +
           "<recipientId>1</recipientId>" +
           "<routingOrder>1</routingOrder>" +
           "<email>abc@test.com</email>" +
           "<name>Rajesh</name>" +
           "</certifiedDelivery>" +
           "</certifiedDeliveries>" +
           "</recipients>" +
           "</envelopeDefinition>";
```

Comment: Thanks Ergin. In docusign API help there are some confusion related to Recipient types. certifiedDeliveries has been mentioned outdated in the Docusign API help page. Your provided solution worked for me.